# Do I need to use [weak self] if I'm making a network request using a singleton networking service?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Suppose I have a networking singleton that uses Alamofire's SessionManager such as this:

import Alamofire

```
class Network {
    static let shared = Network()
    private init() {}

    private var sessionManager: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

                return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }

    func postRequest(params: [String: Any]? = nil, completion: (() -> ())? = nil) {
        sessionManager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params).validate().responseData {
            // do something with response
            completion()
        }       }
}
```

Which I then use in a service class:

```
class SomeService {
    static let shared = SomeService()
    private init() {}

    func doSomePostRequest(params: [String: Any]? = nil, completion: (() -> ())? = nil) {
        Network.shared.postRequest(params: params, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

I then make a request and reload a tableview using this service class:

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBAction func fetchData(_: Any)  {
        SomeService.shared.doSomePostRequest {
            // do i need to use [weak self] here?
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Do I still need to use [weak self] to avoid crashes and strong reference cycles? At any point, the user can dismiss MyViewController by pressing Back.

Am I correct in assuming that I don't need it since the service class is a singleton? And that if I make it an instance in MyViewController, I'd have to use [weak self]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use weak references to objects to make sure they are deallocated when they should be.

A singleton never gets deallocated. Therefore, whether you have a strong, weak, or unsafe pointer doesn't matter. No need to make the reference weak.

Comment: You should look at the code he posted. The weak reference would be to MyViewController, *not* the singleton.

Comment: I get it now. when the closure resolves in the singleton, the MyViewController is deallocated because it's not referencing the singleton as an instance property.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know specifically about Alamofire's SessionManager, but in general, yes, you need to protect against extra retains even if you're using a singleton. In fact, you have to protect against them *especially* because they're singletons.

Looking at your code, the `self` you're worried about is MyViewController. If you create a strong reference to MyViewController in your singleton SomeService, then MyViewController will **never** be released, because your singleton lives for the lifetime of your application. It's not really a retain cycle per say (it's not cyclical), but the effect is the same -- MyViewController and all the objects it retains will never be released.